# angularjs bind data and display from hardcode and or service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hello i have my directive:

```
  myApp.directive('hoverDirective',function($document){
    return function(scope, element, attr){
      scope:{value:'foo'};
      element('mouseover',function(event){
        console.log(event);
      });
    }
  });
```

And I have it working:

```
<div hover-directive>
  {{value}}
</div>
```

But now I want to hardcode data in directive, and get it by factory.
I read about scope:{value:'foo'}. But i have error while i was putting it inside of return function.
Can anyone help ?

UPDATE: I try putting code inside of return function no results.

Comment: For someone to help you, you need to share code around what have you tried.

Comment: `But now I want to hardcode data in directive, and get it by factory. I read about scope:{value:'foo'}. But i have error while i was putting it inside of return function.` I don't get that part, what you really want to achieve, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here : http://jsfiddle.net/qeCDL/

HTML:

```
  <div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
            <div hover-directive></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('hoverDirective', function () {
    return {

        scope: {},
        restrict: 'AE',

        controller: function () {


        },
        template: '<h3>{{value}}</h3>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.value = "hove me";
            element.on('mouseover', function (event) {
                console.log(scope.value);
            });
        }
    };
});


app.controller('firstCtrl', function ($scope) {


});
```